# Process terminated with status 3 - code blocks

Tags: c, sdl

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void pause()
{
    int continuer = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (continuer)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Rect posBack, posbtn_jouer, posbtn_regles;
    SDL_Surface *screen = NULL, *background = NULL, *btn_jouer = NULL, *btn_regles = NULL;

    posBack.x = 0;
    posBack.y = 0;
    posbtn_jouer.x = 400;
    posbtn_jouer.y = 460;
    posbtn_regles.x = 400;
    posbtn_regles.y = 570;

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1080, 720, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    background = SDL_LoadBMP("game_home.bmp");
    SDL_BlitSurface(background,NULL,screen,&posBack);

    btn_jouer = SDL_LoadBMP("btn_jouer.bmp"); 
    SDL_SetColorKey(btn_jouer,SDL_SRCCOLORKEY,SDL_MapRGB(btn_jouer->format,255,255,255));
    SDL_BlitSurface(btn_jouer,NULL,screen,&posbtn_jouer);

    btn_regles = SDL_LoadBMP("btn_regles.bmp"); // Ouverture du bouton regles
    SDL_SetColorKey(btn_regles,SDL_SRCCOLORKEY,SDL_MapRGB(btn_regles->format,255,255,255));
    SDL_BlitSurface(btn_regles,NULL,screen,&posbtn_regles);
    SDL_Flip(screen);

    pause(); 

    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_FreeSurface(btn_jouer);
    SDL_FreeSurface(btn_regles);

    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using SDL and C to program a game, when I compile this code, the message "Process terminated with status 3 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))" appears to me and I don't understand what is the problem. I google it but haven't found anything that can help me... If someone can help me, I'm confused.

Comment: what ever header file (at compile time) and library (at link time) is not being included, so the compile fails due to the `SDL` header file not being included.

Comment: the posted code ALSO does not cleanly compile because the signature for `main()`  is  `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  but the parameters are not being used.  Suggest using the other valid signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level

Comment: Can you show us how the compiler is called?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you're including the correct header file. Are you sure you're not using [sdl-2](/questions/tagged/sdl-2)? If you are, use `<SDL2/SDL.h>` as your header.

Secondly, in

```
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            continuer = 0;
    }
```

`event.type` is not type `char`. Use [if](/questions/tagged/if) statements.

Thirdly, please check that the paths of your [bmp](/questions/tagged/bmp) files are correct. They must begin at the root of your project directory or pointers `background` and `btn_jouer` will be `NULL`.